# How to make two foreach have the same variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I have a function to upload multiple files. I use two foreach  to upload the files. In the first foreach,  I loop the uploaded file,

```
$j_upl      = count($my_upload["name"]);
$isUploaded = 0;
$files      = $_FILES;

for($i=0;$i<$j_upl;$i++){

    $random_name             = substr($my_upload["name"][$i],0,-4)."_".date("ymdhis").$i.substr($my_upload["name"][$i],-4);
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $_FILES['upload_act']['name']       = $files['upload_act']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_act']['type']       = $files['upload_act']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_act']['tmp_name']   = $files['upload_act']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_act']['error']      = $files['upload_act']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_act']['size']       = $files['upload_act']['size'][$i];

    $this->upload->initialize($config);


    $this->upload->do_upload('upload_act');

}
```

In the `$random_name`, I use `.date("ymdhis")` to be added to the file_name. So, the file will be renamed to `the file name."_".datetime uploded`.

In the second foreach, I use this to insert the `$random_name` into the database.

```
foreach($details as $rows){             

    $file_name    = substr($rows['val_upl'],0,-4)."_".date("ymdhis").$ii.substr($rows['val_upl'],-4);               

    $dt_act['UPL_FILENAME']     = ($rows['val_upl'] == "") ? NULL : $file_name.$ii;             

    $this->MProject->ins_activity_m($dt_act);
    $ii += 1;
}
```

I use the same method to get the `$file_name`. If I upload around 2-3 files, the `$file_name` is matching the `$random_name`. But, if there are more files to upload, it begins to not match the `$random_name` because the second in `('Ymdhis')` is different.

What is the best method to get the `$random_name` match the `$random_name` so the inserted file_name is matching the uploaded file_name?

Note:

- I may added something to the file_name, but I prefer not to remove anything (the datetime format should exist)

Comment: Does it matter that the date is the exact second its being uploaded. why not move `date()` outside of the loop with your variables and assign it to a variable and just pass that to both loops? You're still getting the exact time the code starts process the batch as opposed to individually.

Comment: @MatthewBrent yes, I also need the seconds too for another purpose.

Comment: Why not just generate a `$random` value _before_ the loop that you can attach to all the upload file names? Instead of relying on the `date()`?

Comment: @giollianosulit I need the datetime in the file name.

Comment: Well, then put the `date("ymdhis")` and store it as a variable, _before_ the loop and concatenate it in?

Comment: @giollianosulit he cant do that because it needs to be specific to each file, it'll only execute date once that way. then the only way to do this is to create an associative array or object and in your first for loop push the date and other info into the object. then pull that data into your second foreach

Comment: @MatthewBrent - Ah ok I understand now, well if that's the case you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to create an associate array in the first for loop with the required information passed in as key-value pairs. You don't need to loop through this object as you can use keys that you already know the values of within your loop like an existing filename to access the values like below...

```
$file_uploads = array();

for($i=0;$i<$j_upl;$i++){

$random_name = substr($my_upload["name"][$i],0,-4)."_".date("ymdhis").$i.substr($my_upload["name"][$i],-4);

$file_uploads[$my_upload["name"][$i]] = array(
    'new_name' => $random_name,
    'some_other_value' => $some_other_var
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$_FILES['upload_act']['name']       = $files['upload_act']['name'][$i];
$_FILES['upload_act']['type']       = $files['upload_act']['type'][$i];
$_FILES['upload_act']['tmp_name']   = $files['upload_act']['tmp_name'][$i];
$_FILES['upload_act']['error']      = $files['upload_act']['error'][$i];
$_FILES['upload_act']['size']       = $files['upload_act']['size'][$i];

$this->upload->initialize($config);


$this->upload->do_upload('upload_act');

}


foreach($details as $rows){             

$file_name = $file_uploads[substr($rows['val_upl']]['new_name'];               

$dt_act['UPL_FILENAME']     = ($rows['val_upl'] == "") ? NULL : $file_name.$ii;             

$this->MProject->ins_activity_m($dt_act);
$ii += 1;
}
```

**please note** i've not tested this and i'm coding blind here but that should be enough to get you there.

Comment: what is `previousCode.date('ymdhis')` ?

Comment: its just pseudocode...replace previousCode with all your code

Comment: oh okay. I'll try it.

Comment: try my updated code...as I state in the answer i havent tested it but it should be clearer for you to follow

Comment: did this help Vahn? please accept the answer if it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture the exact file names from the first loop, why not build an array within the first loop that just stores the file names? Then you can reference the array by the value of $rows rather than attempt to rebuild the names. (It also depends on what's between these two loops.)

Comment: How to loop the array in the second foreach?

Comment: see below Vahn ... it's just pseudo code but I can clarify if you need it.